# Is it possible to randomly sample from single data set (Monte Carlo style) to create new data sets?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, monte-carlo, type-i-and-ii-errors

### Background

I understand Monte Carlo methods only superficially, but I understand you can repeatedly randomly sample, with or without replacement, from your data set to estimate population parameters (and other things?).

Furthermore, I have been trying to understand, and avoid, common problems which occur when well-meaning researchers [move back and forth between hypotheses and results](/questions/100151/).

### Question

*Can the two concepts be combined to create an infinite number of new data sets?* For example, say I have a small data set ($n = 200$) which I split half into an exploration set (training, or whatever you want to call it), and another half for verification (hold-back, or whatever you want to call it). I come up with some hypotheses and / or models based on the first set, then, holding my breath, verify them with the second set.

Now say I'm not happy with the results. Can I then do a Monte Carlo-type manoeuvre and randomly, with replacement, pluck 100 observations from the original data set and consider that as fresh and untainted? Or is this a wild misapplication of the Monte Carlo concept? Is this going to result in a wild increase in spurious results and a guarantee that no one will let me near a statistical package again in my life?

Answer (score 1):

**Background**

I am afraid what you describe is *the bootstrap method* of Efron (1979) and ***not*** the generic *Monte Carlo method* that is not specifically linked with statistics... Check the Wikipedia entry on bootstrap.

**Question**

The Monte Carlo sample you create by resampling from your data is not "fresh and untainted" since it is a replica of your data (obtained via the empirical distribution). It is useful to get statistical properties of a procedure you built on the original data (like bias, coverage, &tc.), not to create new samples. So I am also afraid the answer is that this proposal is a misapplication of the bootstrap method.